# Can a Slack bot get the thread id that a slash command was sent from?

Tags: post, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Suppose a user types a slash command inside a thread, as opposed to inside the main channel.

Is it possible for to include this information in the request sent to the bot? I want the bot to know where exactly the message came from so that it can reply in the same location (i.e. inside the thread and not in the main channel)

[Judging by the docs](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling), it seems information about threads is not sent. Here is the POST object that the docs say is sent:

```
token=gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO
&team_id=T0001
&team_domain=example
&enterprise_id=E0001
&enterprise_name=Globular%20Construct%20Inc
&channel_id=C2147483705
&channel_name=test
&user_id=U2147483697
&user_name=Steve
&command=/weather
&text=94070
&response_url=https://hooks.slack.com/commands/1234/5678
&trigger_id=13345224609.738474920.8088930838d88f008e0
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if slash commands work in threads. Looking at https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/977264888392413186, they didn't work in threads at least a few months ago...

Comment: I believe it is [still not possible](https://medium.com/@brad.robertson/slack-threading-failure-threadfail-977859586d5a), but [these docs are promising](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-threading). Just appears custom slash commands are still no welcome inside threads :(

Answer (score 0):

Custom slash commands are not supported within threads. From the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#enabling-interactivity-with-slash-commands__what-are-slash-commands):

> Limitations on use:
> Slash Commands cannot be used in message threads. Consider using app
> shortcuts for this purpose instead.

While the documentation lists [app shortcuts](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts/using) as an alternative, you sadly won't receive `thread id` in the payload from shortcuts, so it's not useful for your issue. You can, however, do some other things based on app shortcuts, such as open a modal, and so on, so there's at least that.